# Laravel Blade Undefined variable:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am completely new into Laravel, but keep getting this error. I did follow an tutorial, and did exactly the same as the video, but it doesn't work.

In my /controllers/users.php i have:

```
<?php
class Users_Controller extends Base_Controller {
 public $restful = true;

 public function get_create(){
     return View::make('users.create')->with("title","Bum bum!");

 }
}
?>
```

And in my /views/users/create.blade.php i have:

```
   <h1>Wallah {{$title}}</h1>
```

But i keep getting this error?
Unhandled Exception

```
 Message:

  Error rendering view: [users.create]

  Undefined variable: title
  Location:
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine here, any differences between what you're doing? http://paste.laravel.com/tE2

Comment: Thanks it worked out with Route::get('/users/create', function(){
    return View::make('users.create');
}); i was using sytnax from version 3